# Как искать ".ru" в lua для SAMP?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

когда ищешь ".ru" то язык программирования думаю что символ "." используется как регулярное выражение для поиска([список регулярных выражений](https://uopilot.uokit.com/wiki/index.php?title=String.find_(Lua))), и выходит что любая строка по типу "_ru" будет найдена и воспринята как нужный нам результат, как избежать это регулярное выражение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В шаблонах Lua точка действительно находит любой символ.

Для того, чтобы найти именно символ точки, *вне символных классов* нужно экранировать его с помощью символа `%`: `%.`.

Кроме точки, в шаблонах Lua существуют следующие "волшебные символы" (["magic characters"](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html))

```lua
( ) . % + - * ? [ ^ $
```

Их тоже нужно экранировать вне символных классов.

Comment: спасибо большое